# Wix Installer - "DLL required for this install to complete" error

Tags: wix, wix3.5

When I'm running the installer, I'm getting this error:
There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Any clue?

Code snippet:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Product Id="*" Name="SetupProject1" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="GoGo" UpgradeCode="9bfe9221-2d7d-46ee-b483-88f00e14b4b3">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SetupProject1" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents"/>
    </Feature>

    <!--<Binary Id="WixCA" SourceFile="WixCA.dll" />-->

    <Property Id="QtExecDeferredExample" Value="InstallManager.exe"/>
    <CustomAction Id="QtExecDeferredExample" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixQuietExec"
                Execute="immediate" Return="check" Impersonate="no"/>

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="QtExecDeferredExample" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="SetupProject1" >
          <Component Id='MainExecutable'>
            <File Id='InstallManagerEXE'
                  Name='InstallManager.exe'
                  DiskId='1'
                  Source='InstallManager.exe'
                  KeyPath='yes'/>
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <ComponentRef Id='MainExecutable' />
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>


</Wix>
```

Comment: may be you should log by installing with the following command `msiexec /i SetupProject1.msi /lvoicewarmupx log.txt` and see if the log file log.txt gives any indication to why the error pops.

Comment: log shows: Error 1723. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  Action QtExecDeferredExample, entry: WixQuietExec, library: C:\Windows\Installer\MSIF136.tmp

Comment: try it as an `immediate` action instead of `deferred` after `installFinalize`

Comment: Does this error manifests on a single machine or on every computer that you try to install?

Comment: on multiple machines

Answer (score 3):

Your question has two answers.

**First answer: Generic DLL**

When you set your custom action, there is an attribute `DllEntry="WixQuietExec"`. You need to include the DLL in the package with this code:

```
<Binary Id="WixCA" SourceFile="WixQuietExec.dll" />
```

This tag should be created inside the `Product`.

So your code would be like this:

```
...
<Binary Id="WixCA" SourceFile="WixQuietExec.dll" />
<CustomAction Id="QtExecDeferredExample" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixQuietExec"
              Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />
...
```

Don't forget to match the `CustomAction[BinaryKey]` and `Binary[Id]`.

**Second answer: WixUtilExtension**

Particularly for a standard custom action like **QtExec**, you need only to include a reference to the extension.

1. In Solution Explorer, expand the References in your project
2. Right-click over it and select Add Reference
3. Browse for the folder where the WiX Toolset is installed. Then select bin folder. In my case, the full path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin`
4. Select WixUtilExtension.dll and press Add and then OK

Change the `Wix` tag adding `xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"`. For example, your tag will be:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
```

Comment: Where can I get this dll? I thought it's part of the WixUtilExtension. Reference: [Quiet Execution Custom Action](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html)

Comment: I expanded the answer to cover your particular case.

Comment: Even after following the steps above [see updated code] the same error occurred: Error 1723. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  Action QtExecDeferredExample, entry: WixQuietExec, library: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI3936.tmp

Answer (score 1):

Try change `DllEntry` from `WixQuietExec` to `CAQuietExec` and property use `QtExecCmdLine`

please reference to https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/standard-libraries/silence-please/

Answer (score 1):

I confronted the same issue (error 1157) when I switched from using CAQuietExec extension to WixQuietExec. I used Wix Toolset 3.9 when error occured.

I solved this problem installing Wix Toolset 3.10.1 (it is last stable version now) and WixQuietExec extension works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

For any one facing this issue when developing the custom action using C#, I suggest to ensure that

1. The BinaryKey is referring to the generated *.CA.dll and not the
   actual dll file.
2. Ensure that the method being called is decorated
   with the [CustomAction] attribute.

Comment: Also make sure when you renamed a CA that didn't just do it in the wxs file. Not renaming the the C# method just cost me an hour of fruitless investigation. I don't really know how I managed to do that, but I suppose someone else might.

Comment: Decorating method with the [CustomAction] attribute helped in my case, thanks!